# Options added to [disabled multi] Select field dynamically are not posted?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have dynamically created option elements with javascript. I double click an option from one select field to transfer it to a second, disabled, multiple select field. This works fine. The problem appears when I go to submit the form with the new information. The second select field is not passed to PHP. I'm assuming it thinks its empty, but each of the options I added are selected by default and I visually see them all there. I've been looking around for a solution to this, but am having little luck. Everything I can find says that the most likely cuprit is a browser incompatibility or that the elements are not being added to the form. If it is a browser incompatibility issue, I've tried it on all the major browsers all with the same results, so I would like to know which one I'm missing (FF, Chrome, IE). As for not being added to the form, I don't see how that could be possible. The select element already exists in the form and I am merely appending new options in it. Am I missing something, or is this just not possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function addModule(value, title) {
    modules = document.getElementById('modules');
    modules.options[modules.options.length] = new Option(title, value, true);
}
</script>
<form name="addModules" method="POST" action="submit.php">
<select name="moduleList" size="20" ondblclick="addModule(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text, this.value);">
<?php //dynamically created options from PHP ?>
</select>
<select id="modules" name="modules[]" multiple="multiple" size="20" DISABLED></select>
<input type="submit" value="Add Modules" />
</form>
```

Comment: I only see options added to a **`DISABLED`** field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled fields are not submitted.  The easiest solution is to change it to readonly.  If you're determined to have it as disabled, you could make a hidden field that is updated with values from it, but I strongly suggest just using readonly and then trying to style it as desired.

Comment: That did the trick, never heard of readonly before. Is there any way to prevent options in this field from being unselected? When I had it disabled they would stay selected even when I clicked in the field, now they don't. Thanks! Will accept when I can still waiting on timer...

Comment: @Showerhead Hmmm, did not think that would be possible.  I suppose you could do it with JavaScript.  Another option might be to just use a hidden field and stick with disabled.  I'm surprised though that readonly can be deselected.  Not sure how to work around that without it getting ugly :(.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to avoid hidden fields, otherwise I wouldn't be able to visually verify the selections. Though I could add a new span and populate it with the list as I update the hidden field... hmmmm... Things to think on, thanks again :)

Comment: @showerhead Yeah, there doesn't really seem to be a pleasant answer is readonly's can be deselected.  I would be tempted to use JS to automatically reselect whenever a user deselects one of the readonly's before I went the hidden field route.  Seems like it would be easier to maintain, and it would be just as effective as long as users weren't poking and prodding at it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the second select is disabled, it's data doesn't get sent when the form is submitted.

You could try making it readonly instead of disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard browser behavior. While adding the values to the disabled select list, you can also add it to a hidden input field, and then access this in the posted request.